# How to get transport's response headers from axis1 stub

Tags: java, soap, header, wsdl, axis

May I know how to get response headers from axis 1 soap stub?

**Response Log**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Jetty(8.1.17.v20150415)
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1547
MyHeader: test
Date: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 04:41:20 GMT

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
........
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

From java, I use invoke2 method and pass messageContext to get response header. But failed to get the headers provided above.

```
invoke2(soapBindingStub._getCall().getMessageContext());

public void invoke2(org.apache.axis.MessageContext context) throws AxisFault {   
        System.out.println("invoke 2 called");
        Iterator pros = context.getAllPropertyNames();
        while (pros.hasNext())
            System.out.println("Name : " + pros.next());
        if (!(context.getProperty("transport.http.servletResponse") instanceof HttpServletResponse)) return;

        StringBuilder headers = new StringBuilder();
        HttpServletResponse request = (HttpServletResponse)context.getProperty(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);

        Collection c = request.getHeaderNames();
        Iterator e = c.iterator();
        while (e.hasNext()) {
          String headerName = (String)e.next();
          headers.append(String.format("%s: %s%n", headerName, request.getHeader(headerName)));
        }

        // log 
        System.out.println(headers.toString());
      }
```

Please able to help me to get response headers "*MyHeader*" from axis1 soap stub?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine now.

```
String[] header1 = soapBindingStub._getCall().getMessageContext().getResponseMessage().getMimeHeaders().getHeader("MyHeader");
logger.info(loggerHeader + "header1[0] ="+header1[0]);
```

Thanks.